# Show product files on home page rather to download after payment

Tags: bigcommerce

Show product files on home page or other (template file) rather to download after payment

I want to show product File of downloadable product of bigcommerce store at home page. How can I do this?

I created a Downloadable product and created Product file by browsing and attach that file. Now I want to show that file in home page and any template file category.html etc. Currently This is achieved after making suceessfull payment. The we can download the file form our account(purchaser account)

```
 %%Panel.AccountDownloadItems%%
```

I want to this download panel at my page template. But while I'm using this panel in home page it shows the file is expire rather to download link.

Comment: Can you provide more information? This is fairly vague.

Comment: Alyss I add more details in my question. Plz take a look.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by performing a GET request to the account order history page. The user would have to be logged in, and the page that you request this from must use HTTPs.

This demo below was inserted on the default.html page, and it loads the direct link to past file downloads. The only modification you need to do to this is to use your own URL for `var pastOrdersUrl`, and make sure that it is HTTPS.

## Demo

**HTML CONTAINER TO HOLD RESULTS**

```js
<!-- Downloadable Products -->       
<div id="dlp">
  <h3> Download Previous Purchases </h3>
  <img id="dlp-loading" style="display:none;" src="http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif"/>
  <p id="dlp-login" style="display:none; color:red;"> Please login in order to download past purchases</p>
  <div id="results"></div> <!-- Hold the downloadable products -->
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
<!-- Load ES6 Promise Library to better Manage Async Requests -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/3.0.2/es6-promise.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // If Customer Signed In:
  if ("%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%") { 
    $('#dlp-loading').show(); //Show loading gif (nice effect):
    var pastOrdersUrl = 'https://store-abc123.mybigcommerce.com/account.php?action=order_status'; //Replace with your own HTTPS url.
    get(pastOrdersUrl)
      .then(function(res) {
        $(res).find('.OrderItemList > li > a').each(function() { //For each downloadable product on the order history page...
          $('#dlp-loading').show(); //Continue to show the loading gif.
          get($(this).attr('href')) //Grab it's url (via href attr) & Get content from the item download page...
            .then(function(dl_page) {
              //*** Append the Download Name and Direct Download Link To Results Container ***//
              $('#results').append('<li>' +$(dl_page).find('.DownloadItem > strong').html() +'</li>');
              $('#dlp-loading').hide();
            });
        });
      });
    } else {
      $('#dlp-login').show(); //Tell user to log-in, if not so already.
    }

  /**
   * Performs an HTTP GET request to the provided URL.
   * @param url string - The url to GET.
   * @return Promise - Fulfilled with request's response data. 
   */
  function get(url) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill,reject) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(res) {
          fulfill(res);                   
        }
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Video Demo:**
http://screencast.com/t/8fZmSQVl

The requests to grab each download url all occur asynchronously, so it's super quick. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use that panel the way you intend on the home page. Panels have functionality limited by what page you are trying to use them on.

You could potentially do this through using a web service to hit the API to grab the file. You would need to pass information into the web service from the store front so it knew what files might be available. This might include the most recent order number, or more easily surface-able, the email of the person if they are logged in.

Home page loads -> customer login email determined -> script asynchronously sends a request to web service to identify relevant download links -> web service hits API with the email to find orders -> filters to downloads -> identifies downloadable links -> passes info back to script to load.

Hope that provides some clarity.

Comment: If I want to show product file in product page. Can I do  this by panel or other variable.

Comment: @pank Not yet, with Stencil you might be able to though (currently unreleased) : `https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources#DownItem`
You can copy and paste my client side solution in the meantime, granted it will display `all` file downloads for the customer. You can either do string comparisons with my solution to filter the relevant product, or as mentioned you can use the API to query against product ID (`%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%`) + past customer orders (via customer ID associated with the customer's email (`%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%`)).